# Get-ChildItem to act like ls instead of ls -l

Tags: powershell

When I use Get-ChildItem in PowerShell I get a list of items in a directory formatted in rows. This list often goes off screen, forcing me to scroll up if I want to see the rest of the list or previous commands and outputs. I want to make an alias or function for ls that behaves like ls in unix. I want a compact list of names that are formatted in a tabular fashion.

I have a function that I'm working on that strings all the names together, but it doesn't format the list in a table and does not prevent names from overflowing to the next line:

```
function uls {
(Get-ChildItem $args[0] | select -exp name) -join "`t"
}
```

In sum, is there a way to get a compact ls-like output from Get-ChildItem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Format-Wide`, which has a default alias of `fw`:

```
ls | fw
```

You can control the number of columns with the `-Column` property:

```
ls | fw -c 5
```

Just beware that the output of that command is a string, not a collection of objects, so it wouldn't be useful for pipelining.

Comment: That works wonderfully! Format-Wide also has a -Column flag where you can put in the number of desired columns.